# Javascript char code partly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add char code this to prevent in my JS form. This JS not working if I add this char code :

```
] \ /
```

--

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("userNameRule", function(string, element) { 
    return !string.match(/[.;,`~!@#$%^&*()-+=|{[}'":?><]/g);
    });
```

What I want to do now is, add that the char code into my JS.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pattern contains some reserved characters like `. ^ $ ( ) { } - + ?`

In a character class you should only escape the `-` anyway, because it is intended for range of symbols like `a-z` or `0-9`

try to escape them like so

```
return !string.match(/[\.;,`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+=|\{\[\}'":\?><]/g);
```

(or escape just the `-`)

Comment: You don't need to escape all these characters in a character class…

Comment: oops, so many characters, I didn't noticed the class... :) updated

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I already tried, but still now work for this char : ] \ /

Comment: @TheBijis just escape them using \.

Comment: @JulienRoyer I don't understand. Could you please give an example ?

Comment: return !string.match(/[-\.;,`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\]\+=|\/\\{\[\}'":\?><]/g);